# GASearchCV doesn't support KerasRegressor

Tags: genetic-algorithm

I am using GASearchCV method with Sklearn-genetic-opt.

However, when I use it for hyper-parameter tuning, I got an error as below.

```
283 # Check that the estimator is compatible with scikit-learn
284 if not is_classifier(self.estimator) and not is_regressor(self.estimator):
285     raise ValueError(
286         f"{self.estimator} is not a valid Sklearn classifier or regressor"
287     )
289 if criteria not in Criteria.list():
290     raise ValueError(
291         f"Criteria must be one of {Criteria.list()}, got {criteria} instead"
292     )

ValueError: <keras.wrappers.scikit_learn.KerasRegressor object at 0x000001F0DC8A9EB0> is not a valid Sklearn classifier or regressor
```

How can i use it for hyper-parameter tuning?

Comment: Hi, I think the error us related to the way the keras wrapped is built, the package expects inheritance from the sklearn base estimators, which seems it can't get from this wrapper.

Comment: I'm the author of this package, I'll check it closer to make sure it supports keras wrapper directly

Comment: Thanks for your help. If it is fine, pls let us know. Much thanks

Comment: Hi, Rodrigo A. How's it going about GASearchCV for Keras?

I still get same error. Please let me know, it will be OK to run in Keras.